# How to find picture in Photos that shows up as wallpaper (after Systems Preferences work) in Mojave

Tags: macos, finder, photos

I have a large Photos library with approximately 100+ folders in My Album. I have set System Preferences Desktop to use my complete Photos library as source for wallpaper.
Occasionally I have a desktop wallpaper I would like to find the original Photos picture and folder in My Albums where it is located.

Earlier, in this forum,  I found this command:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "finder" to get posix path of (get desktop picture as alias)'
/Users/snaguru/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/2013/09/29/20130929-164330/P1010004.JPG
```

When I search in Photos for P1010004.JPG I get displayed 16 pictures, none of which is the specific pictures used as wallpaper I am interested in. I have tried to use some parts of this path name to search in Photos but come up with a Not Found response.

Is there a way to find out the exact location in Photos (My Albums and sub-folder/sub-directory) of the original picture used as the wallpaper?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach:
http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/20/show-the-location-path-of-current-wallpaper-in-mac-os-x/
In essence, type the following commands in Terminal.app:

- Reveal the file path of the current wallpaper on the Desktop:

  `defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text -bool TRUE; killall Dock`
- Once revealed, hide the file path from the Desktop:

  `defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text -bool FALSE; killall Dock`

It works this way on all recent macOS versions from 10.10 Yosemite onward (including Catalina).

Comment: Ok. I don't see how to reply to the previous replies.

Comment: I don't see how the previous responses answers the question.

Comment: In the approach I describe, the file path and name will appear centred on the wallpaper when `desktop-picture-show-debug-text` is set to TRUE. You can again hide this info by setting the parameter to FALSE.

Comment: ShutterFreak, I understand that. What I want is the Photos folder name and image name currently being used as wallpaper. The "desktop-picture-show-debug-text" variable doesn't provide me with any information that shows what I want. It only shows me the raw file path of where image is located, which as far as I can tell doesn't give me the Photos folder and image name. Maybe I don't recognize the components (directory, sub-directory, etc) contained in  the full path name for the image being the information I want.

Comment: The problem is that any given photo can be organised in several albums in Photos.app. There is in fact no exact relationship between the Folders/Albums managed by Photos.app (potentially overlapping collections) and the hierarchical folder structure found in a filesystem.

Comment: ShutterFreak, - I guess I am asking the wrong question for what I want to achieve. I have a large Photos library (35k+ photos). I use images in this library as Desktop wallpaper. Occasionally I see a desktop wallpaper that I want to locate. An example is when I see an image with my children at  a young age, I want to send that image to a friend that knew them when they were that age.

Comment: Sifting through Photos library looking for that specific image would take me a very long time to locate. I may know the year range when the image was taken but I may have multiple hundreds  of images in each of that year ranges. Is there a way to locate that specific desktop wallpaper image in Photos? Wishing there was an easy way to locate that image. Thanks

Comment: I hoped I could give you that golden answer, but alas, nothing easy popped up so far. What you could do to more easily find the given photo, is to use the `mdsl`tool or the free command-line utility `exiftool`. You can run it on the picture location displayed on the desktop, e.g.: `mdls ~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/originals/0/000ABC39-2ABB-4BC9-9333-82DA3CDACB33.jpeg` (it will provide you details about the exact date and timestamp the photo was taken)